# how do you reset the validation of a form in formik without clearing the values

Tags: formik

I am using formik and I want to clear the validation of a form without calling `resetForm` which clears the values also,

At the moment,I have tried:

```
setErrors({});
setStatis({ submitCount: 0 );
```

But I cannot find a way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use resetForm(values)?

Formik will set the current values as the new "initial state".

Check my codesandbox code which clears the email inputbox's validation without its value.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-clear-n64vs?file=/index.js